# UITableView, intercepting Edit mode

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm curious if it's possible to intercept the default methods of 'Edit' mode on a UITableView. Typically you get a free 'delete' button if you side swipe a UITableViewCell that has delegate methods associated with it. I'd like to change the delete to some other, arbitrary selector. Instead of deleting the cell, I'd just like to run a hello world alert dialogue. Is something to this extent possible?

Answer (score 21):

Editing is implemented as a method on your UITableView’s delegate object. In your table controller, have whatever control activates editing call this:

```
[tableView setEditing: YES animated: YES];
```

Then, make sure that your delegate object implements this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                initWithTitle: @"Delete" 
                message: @"Do you really want to delete “George W. Bush”?" 
                delegate: self
                cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel"
                otherButtonTitles: @"Of course!", nil];
    }
}
```

…or a more standard action might be:

```
[itemList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
```

Comment: Problem is what to do when the user clicks "cancel." The only thing that I've done that looks half okay is `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` to get rid of the delete button.

Comment: +1 for message:@"Do you really want to delete “George W. Bush”?" ;)

Answer (score 6):

@JFMartin and Marco - to replace the standard 'Delete' button use the following UITableview delegate method

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a property on UITableViewCell called `editAction` which is documented as letting you change the action used for insertion or deletion on individual cells (it uses the cell's `target` property too). I haven't tested it, but this sounds like it might do what you want.

Comment: This feature has been deprecated as of iOS 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a subclass of UITableViewCell and handle touch events in there.  You would likely have to do all the animation stuff yourself, but I think it's probably the easiest solution.  There's not a "Supported" method for changing the delete button, I don't think