# presentmodalviewcontroller hides UITabBar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a basic doubt.I need to push `viewController` to another `viewController` .
and I am trying with code

`Display1 *ac =[[Display1  alloc]init];`

`[[self navigationController]pushViewController:ac animated:YES];`

this gives the option of navigation to previous stack.
I don't option to move on Previous Stack .for that reason I tried `presentModalViewController`

`Display1 *ac =[[Display1  alloc]init];`

`[self presentModalViewController:ac animated:YES];`

But this works fine this one does not give me option to but **presentModalViewController  Hides my UITabBarController**

.is there anyway to, display  UITabBarController with presentModalViewController.
or using pushViewController to not display previous stack

Comment: use this:self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

Answer (score 0):

Darshana Is right If you dont want back option that use

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

before

```
[[self navigationController]pushViewController:ac animated:YES];
```

But if you want UITabBar at new UIViewController than you have to add that controller like this:

```
NextViewController *nextViewController=[[NextViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navBar=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:nextViewController];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navBar animated:YES];
```

I have take this from [PresentModalViewController not showing navigation bar on next view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056726/presentmodalviewcontroller-not-showing-navigation-bar-on-next-view)

But first decide what you want to use PUSH OR MODAL.
this both has different purpose.